# Why can't a qualified type name in an explicit destructor call be parsed correctly?

Tags: c++, destructor, placement-new

Consider an example.

```
#include <string>

struct S {
    S() {
        new (&s) std::string("hi");
    }

    ~S() {
        // does not compile
        // s.~std::string();

        // compiles
        using std::string;
        s.~string();
    }

    union {
        std::string s;
    };
};
```

Why will the commented out portion not compile?

The error message I get from clang shows that the compiler parses `std` by itself as a type.

> identifier 'std' in object destruction expression does not name a type

Why can't the compiler figure out that `std::string` is the type? Is this ambiguous in some way?

I became aware of this from a presentation by Andrei Alexandrescu. It's at 37:10. He quickly comments that this "won't parse" if the type name is qualified but doesn't explain why.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Andrei-Alexandrescu-Systematic-Error-Handling-in-C

(I'm using the word "parse" mostly because he did and I didn't think of a better word. Don't read too far into it. I'm not saying the compiler is doing anything wrong.)

Comment: The `~` is part of an *unqualified-id*, and it can only be followed by a *class-name*, a *decltype-specifier*, or in a pseudo-destructor call a *type-name*.

Comment: Then why does `s.std::~string();` also not work?

Comment: Because `~string()` is not a member of the `std::`namespace?

Comment: According to gcc, a valid way of writing it is `s.std::string::~string();`. clang doesn't like it, though.

Comment: @hvd On the other hand, `s.std::string::~basic_string();` is accepted by clang. Possibly, `s.std::string::~string()` is rejected because `string` is not a member of `std::string` (which is only a typedef). If that's the case, it violates [basic.lookup.qual]/6.

Comment: Nobody mentioned this yet, but `s.~basic_string();` is a correct way.

Comment: As to *why* the standard writers did not specify that `s.~string();` be accepted (without the `using`).. no idea there. There's only one possible thing that can follow the `~` and that is the name of the destructor, so I don't see why all possible sorts of lookup couldn't be used here. There's no possibility of ambiguity, either it finds the destructor or it finds nothing. In fact, why not allow `s.~();` ?

Comment: It is not entirely clear why any of this is needed. It's even more silly than writing say `s.std::string::operator=(t)`, which is valid and correct, but why? (And of course `s.std::~string` is invalid just as `s.std::operator=`).

Comment: @n.m. I don't understand what you mean. This is necessary for explicitly calling the dtor which is necessary if you've used placement new.

Comment: Yes, call s.~string(), that's the correct syntax. Why qualify it with anything?

Comment: @n.m. Ah gotcha, no real reason, just wondering why things are this way.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `std::string`  does not actually name a class type.   Among other things, that means no destructor named `~string()` exists.

`std::string` is, within `<string>`, actually a typedef (alternative name) for a specialisation of a template class type named `std::basic_string<char>`.

A `typedef` of the form `typedef some_class_name another_name` does not cause a destructor to exist named `~another_name`.

Comment: I got the example to work without a `using` by calling it as `s.std::basic_string<char>::~basic_string<char>();`. I don't know if your last sentence is completely accurate though. With a `using` the destructor can be called as `~string`.